# Docker container has no files after copying

Tags: docker, permissions, docker-compose

I'm learning how to work with Docker, trying to practise with book "Microservices with Docker, Flask and React".

Firstly, I've added myself to group `docker` with `usermod` for making all operations without sudo. It has worked, but when I try to run successfully builded image on docker-machine, it says that there are no such file to run.

I have a test project like that:

```
testdriven-app:
|--users-service: 
|  |--project:
|  |  |--__init__.py
|  |  |--config.py
|  |--Dockerfile-dev
|  |--manage.py
|  |--requirements.txt
|--docker-compose-dev.yml
```

Dockerfile-dev:

```
FROM python:3.5.3

# set working directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add requirements
ADD ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

# install requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# add app
ADD . /usr/src/app

# run server
CMD python manage.py runserver -h 0.0.0.0
```

docker-compose-dev.yml:

```
version: '3.3'
services:

  users-service:
    container_name: users-service
    build:
      context: ./users-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './users-service:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"

[kuimov@ms testdriven-app [testdriven-dev]]$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml build
Building users-service
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.5.3
 ---> 56b15234ac1d
Step 2/7 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4caa9194035d
Step 3/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3c347fd7446b
Step 4/7 : ADD ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 417256150884
Step 5/7 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5df631263c71
Step 6/7 : ADD . /usr/src/app
 ---> f97cde6e7e00
Step 7/7 : CMD python manage.py runserver -h 0.0.0.0
 ---> Running in 70ea95e36c1e
Removing intermediate container 70ea95e36c1e
 ---> f3d548a00de1

Successfully built f3d548a00de1
Successfully tagged testdriven-app_users-service:latest
[kuimov@ms testdriven-app [testdriven-dev]]$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up
Recreating users-service ... done
Attaching to users-service
users-service    | python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
users-service exited with code 2
```

I suspect there is a permissions issue because the same container builded with sudo successully runs, but it is quite complicated for me to find out.

Comment: Your `volumes:` block hides everything the Dockerfile does, almost; if you remove it you'll actually run what's getting built into the image.  If you do remove it, do things work better?

Comment: What version of Docker? Are you on Windows or Mac? What directory on the host are you mounting into your container? Have you configured Docker to share that drive/directory into the embedded VM?

Comment: yes, they does! But how to explain that behavior?

Comment: Docker version 18.09.2, Debian 9, info about directory you can see in dockerfile (or I did not understand the question), the last one about configuration is not clear

Comment: I think I've done with it, I have just updated docker-compose, and now it runs without any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it was an old version of docker-compose. I've just upgraded it and now it works.